# How to correctly highlight menu items with a jquery ajax menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, drop-down-menu, sidebar

I have an ajax menu. My goal is to highlight menu items when clicking on them, but also when changing url. On the one hand, I have this code for the click:

```
$('#menuList li a').on('click',function(e){
  $('#menuList li a').removeAttr('aria-current','page').parent().removeClass('activeMenuItem');
  $(this).attr('aria-current','page').parent().addClass('activeMenuItem');

  if($(this).next('ul').length > 0){//if there is a dropdown in the menu item
    e.preventDefault(); 
    $('#menuList li ul').removeClass('activated').attr('aria-haspopup',false);//aria expanded false to all dropdown li
    $(this).next('ul').addClass('activated');//hide dropdown
    $(this).attr('aria-haspopup',true);//add aria expanded true to this dropdown

  }
})
```

This seems to be working fine, but as soon as the page reloads, the active state of the current menu item disappear.Which is normal..

So I'm using also this code (for main links, and for dropdown links)

```
 var url = window.location;//if the page path (main menu) meet the page url
 $('#menuList li a').filter(function() {//add aria and active state to mainmenu li a on load
  return this.href == url;
}).removeAttr('aria-current','page').attr('aria-current','page').parent().removeClass('activeMenuItem').addClass('activeMenuItem');

 $('#menuList ul li a').filter(function() {//if the page path(dropdown) meet the page url
    return this.href == url;//add aria and active state to dorpdown li a on load
  }).removeAttr('aria-current','page').attr('aria-current','page').parent().parent().addClass('activated').siblings().removeClass('activated');
```

This code also seems to work correctly.

The problem is,As soon as I use both at the same time, my menu starts to bug. When I click on a dropdown menu, all the dropdown menus highlight.

Here is my menu structure :

```
 <div id="menu" class="flex-col-xs-12 flex-col-md-2">
    <nav role="navigation" id="navigation" aria-label="Menu principal">
    <ul id="menuList" aria-label="submenu">
      <li><a href="#" class="sidebar_heading" aria-control="guidelineList">menu item 1<span class='fa fa-caret-down right'></span</a>
      <ul id="mysumenu1">
       <li><a href="A">A</a></li>
      <li><a href="B">B</a></li>
      <li><a href="C">C</a></li>
      <li><a href="D">D</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
     <li><a href="#" class="sidebar_heading" aria-control="guidelineList">menu item 1<span class='fa fa-caret-down right'></span</a>
      <ul id="mysumenu2">
       <li><a href="A">A</a></li>
      <li><a href="B">B</a></li>
      <li><a href="C">C</a></li>
      <li><a href="D">D</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="sidebar_heading" aria-control="guidelineList">Guidelines<span class='fa fa-caret-down right'></span</a>
   </li>
</ul></nav></div>
```

So my question : is there a way to highlight menu item bases on click but also when changing url, keep the dropdown menu ope all in the same function??

Comment: I made you a snippet - I tried to make a [mcve] but there is too much code. Could you not break it down into smaller pieces of working code and ask one question at a time?

Comment: If the menu links are getting replaced by your ajax then you need to use [Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). Agree with above comment...hard to narrow down what your exact issue is